# How to make PyQt webkit fast for modern browsing?

Tags: python, browser, pyqt, pyside, qtwebkit

I have been playing around with PyQt4 and have realised that it does not live up to my expectations. Consider the code

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsProxyWidget, QGraphicsView, QPainter
from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebSettings
from batchq.pipelines.interpreters import PythonTerminal
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
import PyQt4

class WithConsole(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, line, source):
        print '%s line %d: %s' % (source, line, msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    webview = QWebView()
    webview.setAttribute(Qt.WA_X11NetWmWindowTypeDesktop)
    webview.setAttribute(Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent, True)
    settings=webview.settings()
    settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
    settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
    settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True)
    settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)
    settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, True)

    page = WithConsole()
    webview.setPage(page)
    frame = webview.page().mainFrame()
    palette = webview.palette()
    palette.setBrush(QPalette.Base, Qt.transparent)
    webview.page().setPalette(palette)

    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
    proxy.setWidget(webview)
    rect = proxy.boundingRect()
    proxy.setPos(rect.width(), rect.height())
    proxy.show()
    scene.addItem(proxy)

    scene.setSceneRect(scene.itemsBoundingRect())
    view = QGraphicsView()
    view.setScene(scene)
    view.setViewport(QGLWidget())

    view.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
    view.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
    view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.BoundingRectViewportUpdate)
    view.show()


    webview.setUrl(QUrl("http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored"))
#    webview.setUrl(QUrl("http://gridster.net/"))
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This implements a minimal web browser which just shows one page with GL enabled for transistions etc. However, testing it on a few webpages one immediately notices that interaction is falling far behind other browsers like Chrome or Safari. In particular, on gridster.net the interaction with the "grid" does not work as one would expect, and for impress.js, the transitions are horrible slow (without GL they are even slower). Finally, this seems to be binding independent. It is also slow with PySide. Qt is version 4.8.1.

My question is, is it possible to make QtWebkit compatible with gridster.js, and how can one improve the performance of transitions?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`QGraphicsWebView`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qgraphicswebview.html), [checkout this link](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/05/17/qtwebkit-now-accelerates-css-animations-3d-transforms/)

Comment: I am afraid that this does not solve the performance issues one experiences with impress.js. But next to that, yes one could probably do all the necessary extension to get it to work with gridster.js.